Trying to find Animal Planet show countdown featuring Cone Snail
I am trying to find an old Animal Planet show that had one of the episode feature a Cone Snail that showcased a commercial filming where one of the actors put the shell to his ear and ended up getting harpooned by the snail, by the way cone snails are absolutely terrifying, a snail with a harpoon that can kill a human that looks just like an ordinary sea shell. 
It is not The Most Extreme or at least The Most Extreme venom episode but I can't find either the show or the commercial video. It was at least in the mid 2000's.
Show would be great episode would be even better

@dbugger nope. I fear the video may be purged as it did show someone actually get harpooned by the snail in the footage and even lying on the beach after.
